# Using @key in a path in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

lets say i have this data

```
{ 
  method: ['twitter','reddit','google'],
  auth: {
    twitter: {id: 213},
    reddit: {},
  }
}
```

i want to list all the methods that are not in auth, or are in auth but dont have an id listed

```
methods in auth with id:

{{#each auth}}
   {{#if id}}
      {{@key}}
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}

methods not in auth with id:

{{#each method}}
   {{#unless (lookup ../auth this)}}
      {{this}}
   {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

What I'm hoping to see is the first part printing out just twitter (since it's the only one that's in auth and has an id), and in the second part it should print out the opposite, both reddit and google.

Right now the second part only prints out google

My current code works for things that aren't in the auth object (google), but it's not able to check if there's an ID defined in the auth object, so it doesn't print out reddit even though it should.

I tried doing  `{{#unless (lookup ../auth this.id)}}` but that prints out all 3, presumably because the lookup is failing.

here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/skeddles/pen/bGjzRZx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. I would just add a second `lookup`:

```
{{#each method}}
   {{#unless (lookup (lookup ../auth this) 'id')}}
      {{this}}
   {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

This takes the result of `lookup ../auth this` and looks for an `id` property on that result. Therefore, only methods that have keys in `auth` that resolve to an object with `id` property will resolve as truthy.

I have [forked](https://codepen.io/76484/pen/ZEjwJmB) your Codepen.

Comment: nice, seems to work! I had the thought of a nested lookup, but couldn't quite figure it out